# Cделать так, чтобы объект постоянно смотрел в сторону камеры

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, augmented-reality

Я использую Unity 2020.2.6f1, и вот что я вижу, когда пытаюсь проверить, как работает приложение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, который отвечает за направленность объекта в сторону камеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если поворачивать объект по оси Y, то можно получить приемлемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но к сожалению при повторной попытке включить приложение для тестирования объект автоматически ставится в это положение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то в скрипте прописать автоматический поворот объекта по нужной оси + направленность всегда в сторону камеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Update` изменяйте параметр `Rotation` на нужный вам:

```
tr.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(1,2,3); //1 - x, 2 - y, 3 - z
```

`tr` - это GameObject, у которого необходимо изменять `rotation`

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь!